# React native - How to change header bar icon programmatacally?

Tags: react-native

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }: { navigation: any }) => ({
            headerTitle: "My Account",
            headerTitleStyle: {
                color: GlobalColors.white,
                fontStyle: "normal",
            },
            headerStyle: {
                elevation: 0,
                shadowOpacity: 0,
                backgroundColor: GlobalColors.themeColor
            },
            headerRight:

                <View style={{ paddingRight: 20 }}>
                  <Text style={{color : GlobalColors.white}}>{next}</Text>
                </View>,
                headerLeft : {isFirst && ( <View style={{ paddingLeft: 16 }}>
                    <Icon
                        name="menu"
                        size={30}
                        color={GlobalColors.white}
                        onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())} />
                </View>)}

        })
```

How to show and hide icon from header. Component will call from two component where every header bar of component has diffrent icon, so i want to change the icon.

Comment: With change you mean change the icon while you are on the same page? Or have two icons, one for each page? I suggest you look at how to create custom headers for `react-navigation`.

Comment: @nikosfotiadis No, i just want to change icon of header bar whenere i want.

Comment: A custom header will definitely allow you to do that. I think this can help you get started https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-a-custom-header-and-custom-bottom-tab-bar-for-react-native-with-react-navigation-969a5d3cabb1